# How to create two dynamic picklists for a Lightning component on App Builder?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Using the `DynamicPickList` class and the `datasource` attribute on the *.design* file is pretty straightforward. I can create a dynamic picklist this way.

> What I want is to be able to have two picklists. One so the user can select the object, and other for him/her to select a field of said object.

I searched for a while now, and it looks like it is not possible to reference another field from the dynamic picklist class. If this is not correct, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The method signature does not have any information about other selected values, so you cannot make a list like this right now.

Comment: That's a shame. I hope it gets introduced on a future release.